# Can I collect fallen arrows that the skeletons shoot at blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I luckily trapped a skeleton and I did something special so they shoot at a block and I tried to collect them but it wouldn't work. I really did think you could do that?

Answer (score 13):

From the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Arrow)

> [...] However, arrows shot by a skeleton cannot be picked up.

Note: If you absolutely want/need those skeleton arrows, there are mods which make it so that you can pick them up.

Answer (score 8):

You can't actually pick them up and put them in your inventory, but you can still use them. You could make a cannon with slime blocks and TNT. When you shoot the arrows (or make the skeleton shoot arrows) into a slime block, then push the slime block up with a piston, the arrows will fly into the air. You can use a nearby TNT explosion to propel them toward a target.

Comment: That's just amazing. Wasting explosives to reuse some arrows. I like the way you think.

Comment: Does this really work? xD

Comment: @SaintSix_ Yes, it really does work. Try breaking a block that has a skeleton arrow stuck in it while standing underneath. You will take damage from the falling arrow.

Comment: Interestingly, as long as the arrows stay loaded, the game should remember them being fired by the Skeleton. docm77 and JL recently put up a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTmg6dc_7yw) using this for getting killed by someone who is not even logged on.

Answer (score 0):

Skeleton shot arrows cannot be picked up by you or any other entity.

Answer (score -3):

No, in vanilla Minecraft, you cannot pick up arrows shot by Skeletons, but you can find mods to let you pick them up if you really want to.

Comment: This adds absolutely nothing beyond what 5pike's answer already states.