# Is there a way to pick up Skeleton Arrows?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way to pick up arrows that have been evaded by my player?

Comment: No clue if this still works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3Ix6pozZ-U

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I collect fallen arrows that the skeletons shoot at blocks?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213114/can-i-collect-fallen-arrows-that-the-skeletons-shoot-at-blocks)

Comment: I don't know if this is a duplicate.  Yes I drew off that question for my answer to this one, but this is for Minecraft PE and not the PC one.

Answer (score 9):

No. You cannot do this in the [PC and console versions of the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/213115/163757) either. As that answer states and the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Arrow#Retrieving) states:

> Arrows originally shot by skeletons, strays, illusioners, pillagers, players in Creative, players using the Infinity enchantment, or duplicate arrows created by Crossbows with the Multishot enchantment cannot be collected.

With the exception of mods for the PC version, its not possible in any version of the game including Bedrock Edition.  This is likely due to the fact that it would make it pretty easy to farm arrows form a skeleton.

Answer (score 7):

**No**. Arrows shot by skeletons cannot be picked up by the player. Only arrows shot by the player (without the infinity enchantment) and missed can be picked up.